# oracle sql : count group by having

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B.

Both table have a column Prod_id i.e both table can be joined on this column like,

```
A.Prod_id = B.Prod_id
```

Prod_Id is not primary key of any of these two table.Both table has different primary key column.

A Prod_id column have following values:

```
  prod_id
--------------
111
222
111
333
222
```

B Prod_id column have following values:

```
  prod_id
--------------
111
222
111
111
333
222
333
```

B table will always have more(111,333) or same(222) number of rows for any Prod_Id as compared to the count of rows of that same Prod_id in A table.

I have to write a query to find out those Prod_id for which B table has more number of rows than A table.

I have other conditions which I have to use in where clause using other columns. But those are not relevant here.

Can you please help me out? I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.prod_id
FROM (
  SELECT prod_id, COUNT(*) AS prodCount
  FROM tableA
  GROUP BY prod_id
  ) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT prod_id, COUNT(*) AS prodCount
  FROM tableB
  GROUP BY prod_id
  ) b ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id
WHERE b.prodCount > a.prodCount
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/020979/1)</kbd>

This gets the count for each prod_id in tableA, and in tableB, JOINS them by prod_id and validates what are the ones in B that appear more times than in A.

As suggested by Gordon, here's a version that takes into account the possibility tat tableA has no records for prod_id:

```
SELECT b.prod_id
FROM (
  SELECT prod_id, COUNT(*) AS prodCount
  FROM tableA
  GROUP BY prod_id
  ) a
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT prod_id, COUNT(*) AS prodCount
  FROM tableB
  GROUP BY prod_id
  ) b ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id
WHERE b.prodCount > a.prodCount
  OR a.prod_id IS NULL
```

For these records, a.prod_is is going to be NULL, since we are doing a RIGHT JOIN.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28481/2)</kbd>

Comment: I think this would be more accurate if it took into account the possibility that `tableA` might have no rows at all for a given `prod_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Thanks for the suggestion. I added a query to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your primary key is named `pk`, this will produce your desired result:

```
select
  b.prod_id,
  count(distinct a.pk),
  count(distinct b.pk)
from
  b left join a on a.prod_id = b.prod_id
group by
  b.prod_id
having
  count(distinct b.pk) > count(distinct a.pk)
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62617/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a0fd/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( prod_id ) AS
          SELECT 111 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 222 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 111 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 333 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 222 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b ( prod_id ) AS
          SELECT 111 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 222 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 111 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 111 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 333 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 222 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 333 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   prod_id
FROM     a
GROUP BY prod_id
HAVING   COUNT(1) < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM b WHERE a.prod_id = b.prod_id )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a0fd/1/0)**:

```
| PROD_ID |
|---------|
|     333 |
|     111 |
```

Answer (score -1):

```SQL
select t2.prod_id
(select count(*) amount, A.prod_id from A group by prod_id) t1,
(select count(*) amount, B.prod_id from B group by prod_id) t2
where t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
and t2.amount > t1.amount
```

Comment: Isn't this query missing a FROM clause? Maybe you can explain a bit what you are doing so people can learn from it.

Comment: Malformed query. Missing the FROM clause